# Print date from yaml to ruby using middleman

Tags: ruby, date, yaml, middleman

I am making a comic book collection app using Middleman.

I am able to get different information from a YAML file and render it in a .erb file.

Now, I created a date using yaml like this:

```
date: 1977-08-01
```

I tried looking around the web on how to render it in different format, but I can't find ANYTHING...

Per example, I have a title field, in my yaml document, that goes like this:

```
title: "Uncanny X-Men"
```

So I render it in my erb document using this:

```
<%= comic["title"] %>
```

But how do I get, let's say, to print the month from my date?  Impossible to find any kind of information... I do get how to use different aspects of dates in either ruby or yaml, but not how to render a date FROM yaml to ruby :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse your `date` value in the YAML file into a Ruby date class, first make sure to surround your date values in the YAML file with quotes like so:

```
date: '1977-08-01'
```

and then to parse:

```
<%= Date.parse(comic["date"]) %>
```

and to get the month you would add `.month` 
like so:

```
<%= Date.parse(comic["date"]).month %>
```

that will give you the number `8` if you want more customization to the way your month look like you should look into [strftime](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Time.html#method-i-strftime), if so you wouldn't even need to use `.month`.

Ideally to DRY things up, you would create a helper in the `config.rb`

```
# Methods defined in the helpers block are available in templates
helpers do
  def format_date(date_txt)
    date = Date.parse(date_txt)
    date.strftime("%B")
  end
end
```

And later you can call it inside your template like so:

```
<%= format_date(comic["date"]) %>
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

First, check the data type with: `comic['date'].class`

If it's a Date then you can use: [strftime](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) to format the date however you want!

If it's not a date let us know and we'll explain the options for conversion